# Starting point for linux kernel update

Tags: linux-kernel, android

My android device runs on Linux localhost 4.14.193+-ab517 #1 SMP PREEMPT Fri Dec 8 03:28:21 CST 2023 armv8l Android (info from uname -a). I humbly request the community for the suggestions on how should I proceed to update this Linux kernel?

Comment: Good luck to find all drivers for your phone on vanilla kernel. Manufacturers *forget* to publish it (it costs time, and people may look the quality of the code).

Answer (score 1):

ask your device manufacturer, you don't have a lot of other options ;-)